# Not looping through for loop - javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

The for loops in the following code dont seem to get activated.

```
var updateMobs = function(){
    for (var b = 0; b < mobsBlue; b++){
        BM = mobsBlue[b]
        BM.x = BM.x - 1

        doCollision(BM, redBase, BM)
        doCollision(BM, debugPlayer, BM)
        console.log("draw1")
        BM.Draw(ctx, false)
    }
    for (var r = 0; r < mobsRed; r++){
        RM = mobsRed[r]
        RM.x = RM.x + 1

        doCollision(RM, blueBase, RM)   
        doCollision(RM, debugPlayer, RM)
        console.log("draw2")
        RM.Draw(ctx, false)
        for (var bb = 0; bb < mobsBlue; bb++){
            BM = mobsBlue[bb]
            console.log("draw3")
            BM.Draw(ctx, false)
            RM.Draw(ctx, false)
        }

    }

}
```

also, feel free to comment any improvements i could do to my code to make this work better if you have any. I also understand i dont have semi colons on the end of my javascript so dont comment me on that

I do not get any errors and mobsBlue and mobsRed are both arrays.

Also, I am calling this function in a loop.

I am sorry for insulting. It was uncalled for and i should of awnsered the question :|. Thanks for helping me out though

My sincere apologies

Comment: it's a function. you have to call it.

Comment: also, `b < mobsBlue` and `BM = mobsBlue[b]` is surprising. Is `mobsBlue` a number or an array?

Comment: read edited question

Comment: do you mean `b < mobsBlue.length` and `r < mobsRed.length` and `bb < mobsBlue.length`?

Comment: the trivial error you make qualifies you for being asked if you actually call the function. (and insulting people is unlikely to get you any help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is a function, make sure to call it with `updateMobs();`.

I believe `mobsBlue` and `mobsRed` are arrays (since you call `mobsBlue[b]` and you index it), so for your `for` loop, you want to loop `for (var b = 0; b < mobsBlue.length; b++){`

As such:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for(var i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
    item = arr[i]
    alert(item)
}
```

Here is your edited code:

```
var updateMobs = function(){
    for (var b = 0; b < mobsBlue.length; b++){
        BM = mobsBlue[b]
        BM.x = BM.x - 1

        doCollision(BM, redBase, BM)
        doCollision(BM, debugPlayer, BM)
        console.log("draw1")
        BM.Draw(ctx, false)
    }
    for (var r = 0; r < mobsRed.length; r++){
        RM = mobsRed[r]
        RM.x = RM.x + 1

        doCollision(RM, blueBase, RM)   
        doCollision(RM, debugPlayer, RM)
        console.log("draw2")
        RM.Draw(ctx, false)
        for (var bb = 0; bb < mobsBlue.length; bb++){
            BM = mobsBlue[bb]
            console.log("draw3")
            BM.Draw(ctx, false)
            RM.Draw(ctx, false)
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**#1** Calling someone who can't understand this simple code 'retarded' is extremely offensive.

**#2** Are you calling the updateMobs function somewhere in the other code?

**#3** I'm assuming mobsBlue is an array like ***njzk2*** said, maybe you meant to get its length? use:

```
for (var b = 0; b < mobsBlue.length; b++)
```

same for mobsRed.

Comment: I did apologise. I am sorry.

Comment: ^^ we all get frustrated when it comes to coding sometimes :D